# Load page on URL search works only from index.php form submission. -JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I created a page that loads a box when it finds the word `result` in the URL,

after form submission it handles the form Data on a separate page and redirects to the URL it came from with `result=name` parameter added, like

*localhost/folder/index.php?result=name*

or

*localhost/folder/index.php?page=page1&result=name*

It supposed to load with this function, and it works only if the form was submitted from clear `index.php` page

```
<script>
  function loadpageFromhistory(nameInAdress, loadinto, page) {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf(nameInAdress) > -1) {
                $(loadinto).load(page);
            }
        };
    loadpageFromhistory("result", "#result", "form_handlers/result.php");

</script>
```

if the form was submitted from `index.php?page=page1`
the box wont show or **will appear for a moment**.

I load the "Menu" page with this function:

```
  //load page on btn click
        function btnload(idbtn, loadinto, page) {
            $(idbtn).click(function() {
                $(loadinto).load(page);
            })
        }; 

  //btnload() & loadpageFromhistory() COMBINED
        function btnNavigationAndAdress(idbtn, nameInAdress, loadinto, page) {
            btnload(idbtn, loadinto, page);
            loadpageFromhistory(nameInAdress, loadinto, page);
        };

btnNavigationAndAdress("#page1btn", "page1", ".body", 'base/pages/page1.php')
```

URL changes with this one, added directly to the nav btns:

```
    /SEARCH PARAMS IN URL
function searchParameters_inUrl(url) {
    //add all reserved params on page load
    var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (params.has("result") && params.has("page")) {

    var parameters_after_page = window.location.search.split('&');
    parameters_after_page.shift();


    parameters_after_page.forEach(function(d) {
        var pair = d.split('=');

        url.searchParams.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
    })
} else if (params.has("result")) {
    //get parameters
    var parameters_after_page = window.location.search;
    //convert to string
    parameters_after_page = parameters_after_page.toString();
    //remove the '?' mark
    parameters_after_page = parameters_after_page.substr(1, parameters_after_page.length);
    //split all parameters
    var splitted_parameters = parameters_after_page.split('&');


    // alert(splitted_parameters);
    splitted_parameters.forEach(function(d) {
        //alert(d);
        var pair = d.split('=');

        url.searchParams.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
    })
    var url = new URL(url);

}
```

}

// this func is added inline to the navigation btns `onclick="address(this)"` / to update the url

```
function address(i) {
    val = i.value;

    var clean_url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];

    var url = new URL(clean_url);
    url.searchParams.append('page', val);



    searchParameters_inUrl(url);
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, url);

}



function addressIndex(i) {

    var clean_url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];

    var url = new URL(clean_url);

    searchParameters_inUrl(url);


    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, url);

}
```

what is the problem here?

UPDATE
well, I finally understood.
the problem is not here and I don't have any idea what that might be.
I tried to load this page with ajax form submission,
and it works the same. Loads the block only if the form submitted from the index page.
any clue?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233508/discussion-on-question-by-andyr-load-page-on-url-search-works-only-from-index-ph).

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
I had a `div.body` in the index page, in this block I placed the result block,
the `.body` block loads the contents with `php include`, so every time it loaded another page , the `.result` block was erased.

Hope you'll notice where you put your divs..